# Traverse resultant 2D array after integer partition

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, integer-programming, dynamic-programming

I have used the solution of integer partitioning using dynamic programming explained in [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/812/partition-of-a-positive-integer-n?newreg=d9aa028bb9cd4acf8af2c7bc33691976) and in [this article](http://www.programminglogic.com/integer-partition-algorithm/).

Following is the resultant matrix when $N$ is equal to $6$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3
\\ 0 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5
\\ 0 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 7
\\ 0 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 9 & 10 & 11
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have tried to obtain the respective partitions of the integer by traversing the matrix again. But it does not add up to the sum required. How do we extract the sequences of the partitioning from the matrix above?

Comment: Do you expect to retrieve the 11 partitions of 6 from the above matrix? (6), (51), (42), (411) etc? That will not work! The matrix above is a slightly modified version of the recursion for the number of partitions of n with largest part k (k<=n): p(n,k)=p(n-1,k-1)+p(n,n-k). This recursion allows you to count the partitions *without generating them*.

Comment: The first article posted clearly states the purpose of the algorithm, that is, to generate all possible partitions of **n**. It also uses DP instead of recursion.